# Medir tamaño del pie

Tags: python, opencv

buenas tardes a todos quisiera pedirles su ayuda con un problema que tengo se trata de lo siguiente:
necesito hacer en web una pagina que al yo subir una foto de un pie pueda calcular la talla de el mismo, encontré este ejemplo en Python y funciona,
http://motion.youngstudies.com/index.php/2018/01/25/measuring-feet-with-opencv/
la cuestión es que lo hacen con una silueta del pie trate de hacerlo con una imagen de un pie pero no funciona, la librería que estoy usando se llama opencv, agradecería si alguien me puede colabora

```
def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
return (ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5
```

def calculesize(file):
image = cv2.imread(file)
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 300)

```
# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
# in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

# find contours in the edged image, keep only the largest
# ones, and initialize our screen contour
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
A4 = None


# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then
    # we can assume that we have found our A4 Page
    if len(approx) == 4:
        A4 = approx
        break


#Extracting A4
box = cv2.minAreaRect(A4)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
box = perspective.order_points(box)

# unpack the ordered bounding box, then compute the midpoint
# between the top-left and top-right coordinates, followed by
# the midpoint between bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates
(tl, tr, br, bl) = box
(tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
(blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)

# compute the midpoint between the top-left and top-right points,
# followed by the midpoint between the top-righ and bottom-right
(tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
(trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)


# compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))

# pixelPerMetric is 8.27 inch as A4 standard width
pixelsPerMetric = dB / 8.27


# compute the size of the A4
dimA = dA / pixelsPerMetric
dimB = dB / pixelsPerMetric

# draw the object sizes on the image
cv2.putText(image, "{:.3f}in".format(dimA),
            (int(tltrX - 15), int(tltrY - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.putText(image, "{:.3f}in".format(dimB),
            (int(trbrX + 10), int(trbrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)

#Now we got the A4 we will calculate every possible contour inside it
#First Crop from extracted box information, we will use same methodology
#as used in A4 detection, naming is almost similar for understanding purpose
cropped = image[int(box[0][1]):int(box[2][1]),int(box[0][0]):int(box[2][0])]
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayscale = cv2.bilateralFilter(grayscale, 11, 17, 17)
edges = cv2.Canny(grayscale, 30, 200)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None, iterations=1)
edges = cv2.erode(edges, None, iterations=1)

contr = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contr = contr[0] 

(contr, _) = contours.sort_contours(contr)

footPrint = None

#Detecting FootPrint
for A in contr:
    # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
    if cv2.contourArea(A) < 1000:
        continue
    footPrint=A
        #footPrint=A


boxed = cv2.minAreaRect(A)
boxed = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(boxed) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(boxed)
boxed = np.array(boxed, dtype="int")
boxed = perspective.order_points(boxed)
#Outline of FootPrint
cv2.drawContours(cropped, [boxed.astype("int")], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
#Circles as Node Points on Bounding Box
for (x, y) in boxed:
    cv2.circle(cropped, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

#a,b,c,d goes as topleft,topright,bottomright,bottomleft Co-ordinate Point 
(a,b,c,d) = boxed    
(topmidX,topmidY) = midpoint(a,b)
(btmmidX,btmmidY) = midpoint(c,d)

(lftmidX,lftmidY) = midpoint(a,d)
(rgtmidX,rgtmidY) = midpoint(b,c)


disA = dist.euclidean((topmidX, topmidY), (btmmidX,btmmidY))/pixelsPerMetric
disB = dist.euclidean((lftmidX,lftmidY), (rgtmidX,rgtmidY))/pixelsPerMetric
cv2.putText(image, "H: {:.3f}in".format(disA),
        (int(20), int(50)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.putText(image, "W: {:.3f}in".format(disB),
        (int(20), int(80)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", image)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor añade más información, ¿Por qué no funciona? ¿Qué resultado te da? ¿Cuál sería el esperado?

Comment: Gracias por responder por que el encuentra al parecer la hoja pero cuando convierte el contenido de la hoja a escala de grises ya luego no encuentra el pie, la verdad no conozco mucho el proceso